# How to use try-catch in promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Take this code, we have a `promise` that contains a `try-catch` statement. 
The body of the `try` calls a function that will fail, and i want to pass the error onward to the `catch` method of the promise.

```
function failingFunc() {
    let undef = undefined;
    return undef.nope();
}
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        let thisWillFail = failingFunc();
        resolve(thisWillFail); 
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e); // (1) Cannot read property 'nope' of undefined
    }
});
promise.then(v => {
    console.log(v);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // (2)
});
```

However it blows up at *(1)* and never reaches *(2)*. 
Why is this? And how can i get the desired functionality?

**Edit1:** 
I'm running in Node, and this is the exact error i get:

[image: Screenshot of error]

**Edit2:** 
Removing the `try-catch` results in pretty much the same:
[image: Screenshot of error]

**Edit3:** 
Turns out this is a known *"bug"* when using vscode to debug Nodejs. 
 
As its explained [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1746#issuecomment-255617404)  this happens due to some sort of mismatch in delivery and expectations between the node implementation of Promise and the error handler in vscode. 
This can be circumvented by turning off all error handling in vscode, however that's likely to change in the future.

**Final Edit:** 
I've posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282653/why-does-vs-code-break-on-handled-exception-from-reject-in-promise/) summarizing what we know about this apparent bug.

Comment: *"However it blows up at (1) and never reaches (2)."* What makes you think that? It certainly does when I try it.

Comment: it does reject...

Comment: I've pasted your code into a Stack Snippet in your question, and added text to the `console.log` at (2). It clearly gets to (2).

Comment: I just pasted this into my chrome 59 console - it doesn't catch the exception (ie there's no "the error is" logged)

Comment: I believe Chrome dev tools has an option "break on all exceptions". Please check whether that is set, which would explain the behaviour.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder im running it in Node.js v6.11.1 and it blows at _(1)_

Comment: @Josh Cannot reproduce. What *does* it do for you?

Comment: It's also worth noting that that entire `try/catch` is unnecessary. An error thrown in the executor of a promise is converted into a rejection anyway. Literally just replace that whole `try/catch` with `resolve(failingFunc())`.

Comment: @Olian04: I suspect you're being confused by the fact you're logging the error from your `catch` handler. If you don't do that (e.g., you handle the error, or log something generic), you'll see your `catch` handler is handling it. (Or just add the label I added when doing the snippet.) (And yes, it works in Node too; double-checked just on the off-chance.)

Comment: @Olian04: I'm not going to get into an edit war with you, but why would you *remove* the snippet? It was useful.

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou: Does for me if I copy and paste the code from the (now removed) snippet into Chrome's console. Version 59.0.3071.115.

Comment: @Olian04: The screenshots show nothing to suggest that your code doesn't reach the `catch` handler. Just that your environment is breaking on raised exceptions (even if handled). Usually they don't do that, but many have an option to enable it for debugging. If you continue execution, you'll follow the path of your error handling (e.g., the `catch` handler).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, do you happen to know the setting for vs code?

Comment: @Olian04: Sadly, no. :-) (I *really* want to get a chance to use VS Code, I hear it's excellent.) It'll be along the lines of the one trincot mentioned above in Chrome's devtools, "break on all exceptions" or "break on thrown exceptions" or similar. I don't think any of us has said this explicitly, so just for clarity: *"And how can i get the desired functionality?"* That code does provided the functionality you're looking for (although again, the `try/catch` is unnecessary, you can just remove it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i found the setting, however it was already set to only catch unhandled errors. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1746#issuecomment-255617404) where its explained that this is a mismatch in delivery and expectations between the node implementation of Promise and the error handler in vscode. (Also, yes. It is awesome, for the most parts...)

Comment: @Olian04: Nice one finding that bug. That's unfortunate x 2 -- that it happens and that it *still* happens a year and a half later. But at least it's specific to exceptions thrown immediately by the promise executor (as opposed to asynchronously).

Comment: @Olian04: I suggest deleting this question, and posting a new question saying, basically, "Why does VS Code break on this handled exception?" and describing what causes it, with a link to that bug, in a self-answer -- so you can share this useful info with others. I had a quick search and don't see a duplicate here on SO (but you'd want to have a more thorough search before posting).